# The csvtojson converter ignores my file name and just puts undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

Basically, when I just run csvtojson module on node.js without any code, it works perfectly. But once I put it into the function, it just comes out with undefined even though my file path is still there.

Js code:

```
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
// create a new converter object
var converter = new Converter({});
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

// call the fromFile function which takes in the path to your 
// csv file as well as a callback function

var  woops;

var createNewEntries = function(db, woops, callback) {

converter.fromFile("./NTA-SAM-Inventory-List-Security-Management-
                   New_2017.csv",function(err, result){
    // if an error has occured then handle it
    if(err){
        console.log("An Error Has Occured");
        console.log(err);  
    } 
    // the result of the conversion
        console.log(result);
        console.log('ohhhhh');
        woops=result;
});
console.log(woops);
};
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
        createNewEntries(db, woops, function(){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            else{
                console.log(woops);
            }
            db.close();
        });
        },2000);

    });
```

This is just testing out whether it converts inside a function and it just shows

`undefined
[]
ohhhhh` 
without converting at all when in a function. So exactly what did I do wrong. By right it should have convert after calling the function. Does it have to do with my code executing before the function ? I already put a `setTimeout` just to give it some time to do so I assume it shouldn't have to do with the order of my code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by it works on its own? Do you mean outside of the function?

Comment: @AakashVerma Forgot to state about running it on node.js. Basically, it runs perfectly without putting it in the function on node.js but once I put it in the function, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try below code for your file name:

```
__dirname + "/NTA-SAM-Inventory-List-Security-Management-
                       New_2017.csv"
```

Replace your code for  `converter.fromFile()` , Now your code would be like that:

```
    converter.fromFile(__dirname + "/NTA-SAM-Inventory-List-Security-Management-
                               New_2017.csv" ,function(err, result){
        // if an error has occured then handle it
        if(err){
            console.log("An Error Has Occured");
            console.log(err);  
        } 
        // the result of the conversion
            console.log(result);
            console.log('ohhhhh');
            woops=result;
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
        createNewEntries(db, woops, function(){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            else{
                console.log(woops);
            }
            db.close();
        });
        },2000);

    });

    });
```

Hope it will work for you.

If the above code are not wouking then try below code with `fast-csv` module:

```
var fcsv = require('fast-csv');
var fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Get the records from csv
 */

var writeZipCodes = function () {
var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + "/NTA-SAM-Inventory-List-Security-Management-New_2017.csv");

fcsv
  .fromStream(stream, { headers: true }) // headers for columns
  .on("data", function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          var woops=data;
          MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
            createNewEntries(db, woops, function(){
                if(err)
                    throw err;
                else{
                    console.log(woops); 
                }
                db.close();
            });
            },2000);

        });
})
  .on("end", function () {
         console.log("done");
});
}

 writeZipCodes();
```

Comment: You forgot to remove my comment from the code while copying :D Not saying you've plagiarised.

Answer (score 0):

According to your output,

```
undefined
[]
ohhhhh
```

---

```
var  woops;

var createNewEntries = function(db, woops, callback) {

converter.fromFile("./NTA-SAM-Inventory-List-Security-Management-
                   New_2017.csv",function(err, result){
    // if an error has occured then handle it
    if(err){
        console.log("An Error Has Occured");
        console.log(err);  
    } 
    // the result of the conversion
        console.log(result);        // This is getting printed second
        console.log('ohhhhh');      // This is getting printed third
        woops=result;
});
console.log(woops);                 // This is getting printed first
};
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
        createNewEntries(db, woops, function(){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            else{
                console.log(woops); // This is useless!
            }
            db.close();
        });
        },2000);

    });
```

You can clearly see this as `woops` variable is just declared so it must be having `undefined` value. And something before `ohhhhh` must be the result variable.

Now, this definitely means that at least the `woops` variable is not getting printed after `ohhhh` or rather, the `createNewEntries` is getting executed or is returning the result after `console.log(woops)` is being executed which that means *your setTimeout()'s time is not sufficient*.

And why are you even using the `callback` and passing it a function when you're not even using it??? Use this instead-

```
var  woops;

var createNewEntries = function(db, woops) {

converter.fromFile("./NTA-SAM-Inventory-List-Security-Management-
                   New_2017.csv",function(err, result){
    // if an error has occured then handle it
    if(err){
        console.log("An Error Has Occured");
        console.log(err);  
    } 
    // the result of the conversion
        console.log(result);
        console.log('ohhhhh');
        woops=result;
}).then(console.log(woops));
};

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        createNewEntries(db, woops);
});
```