# CSV file read issue in firebase functions

Tags: json, firebase, csv, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to read a csv file in a firebase function so that I can process the file and do the rest operations using the data.

```
import * as csv from "csvtojson";
const csvFilePath = "<gdrive shared link>"

try{
    console.log("First Method...")
    csv()
    .fromFile(csvFilePath)
    .then((jsonObj: any)=>{
     console.log("jsonObj....",JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
    })

    console.log("Second Method...")
    const jsonArray=await csv().fromFile(csvFilePath);
    console.log("jsonArray...", JSON.stringify(jsonArray))
         }
catch(e){
    console.log("error",JSON.stringify(e))
}
```

The above mentioned are the 2 methods I have tried for reading the csv but both shows the firebase error

> 'Error: File does not exist. Check to make sure the file path to your csv is correct.'

In case of '`csvFilePath`' I have tried 2 methods

1. Just added the csv file in same folder of the function and added the code like

   ```
   const csvFilePath = "./student.csv"
   ```
2. Added the same file to google drive and changed the access permissions to anyone with the link can read and edit and given the path to same

   ```
   const csvFilePath = "<gdrive shared link>"
   ```

Both shows the same error. In case of google drive I don't want to use any sort of google credential because I was intented to read a simple csv file in firebase function.

Comment: Same issue for me. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Can you please share feedback on my answer to know if further assistance is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I will start by proposing that you convert your csv to json locally or without the function and see if it works. This is because I see you are using ES6 imports which might be causing an issue since all the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) uses `require`. You can also try [CSV Parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser) or some solutions provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831250/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-node-js) as an alternative, trying them without the function to check if it actually works and discard it. Actually, you can upload the JSON once you have converted it from the csv, but that depends on what you are trying to do.

I think the best way to achieve this, is following the approach given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61038414/getting-some-problem-to-read-the-csv-file-inside-the-firebase-functions), that first [uploads the file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files) into cloud storage and using [`onFinalize()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) to trigger the conversion.

Also, will address these three questions that went through similar issues with the path. They were able to fix it by adding `__dirname`. Each one has some extra useful information.

[Context for "relative paths" seems to change to the calling module if a module is imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54596867)

[The csvtojson converter ignores my file name and just puts undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44966843)

[How to avoid the error which throws a csvtojson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943937)